# Pass pdf file to client from php using puppeteer (Node.js)

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf, puppeteer

I would like to download pdf by clicking the button from the webpage using php and node.js

For testing, I got the pdf as I should and everything is ok by calling directly to the node server.

but using PHP as a middle man the pdf is broken
How can I fix it so I just will be able to change the filename in PHP and send it to the angular app

another thing is that if I open the PDF from an Adobe software it's working but in the chrome browser I got that the file is broken

this is the flow :

angular `: $window.location.assign("server-pdf.php)`;

php : sending HTML string to a node server and get pdf file as response to pass it back to the client

```
 $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                            'Content-Type: text/html',
                           )
                    );
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($parameters));
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        http_build_query($parameters));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch); 
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
    echo $res;
```

node.js code - puppeteer

```
    let browser, buffer
    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        })
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
        buffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'})
    } finally {
        try {
            browser.close()
        } catch (err) {
            this.logger.error('puppeteer browser was not closed', err)
        }
    }   
    return buffer
}
```

then using koa I return the body

```
ctx.response.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
ctx.body = buffer
```

I go pdf string if i print the result in php, it looks like:

```
%PDF-1.4
%��
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m72)
/CreationDate (D:20190110075210+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20190110075210+00'00')>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 150
/Height 100
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Filter /DCTDecode
/ColorTransform 0
/Length 3081>> stream
JFIF``;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 65C
```

Comment: Is it not possible to bypass PHP completely? If not can you just save pdf to temp folder from puppeteer and pass a link to it?

Comment: Have you find any solution?